# Override django-admin edit form field values for encrypted data

Tags: django, django-admin

I have values in a database that are encrypted, how can I override django's admin edit form so that the fields can display the decrypted data? Just to clarify I know how to decrypt the values I just need to know how to get the decrypted values into the fields. Is there a django signal for the change_view method that I could perhaps use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while it's possible to override the modelform used by your modeladmin [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options), in this case i would consider using a [custom field type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/), and building in the encryption/decryption into the database serialisation/deserialisation