# Override admin.TabularInline fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override django-admin edit form field values for encrypted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957136/override-django-admin-edit-form-field-values-for-encrypted-data)

The inline model has encrypted data and I need to override the method that renders each field in admin.TabularInline to decrypt the data.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957136/override-django-admin-edit-form-field-values-for-encrypted-data/7957201#7957201

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add functions to your `TabularInline` and then show them as fields:

```
class MyTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    readonly_fields = ['decrypt_first_field', 'decrypt_second_field']

    def decrypt_first_field(self, obj):
        if obj.first_field:
            return decrypt(obj.first_field)
        else:
            return 'Nothing here ...'

    def decrypt_first_field(self, obj):
        ...
```